# Wordpress coding standards. Tabs instead of spaces?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have noticed that Wordperss coding standards prefer TABs over spaces for indenting. Their documentation say "a real tab." I'm not sure what does that "real tab" mean. Is it a TAB key press that inserts 4 spaces? Or is it a 100% TAB just like in Golang programming language?

Comment: An actual TAB. Not four spaces. That's what they mean.

Comment: Is that TAB thing only for php files or the same is applied to html, css, and javascript files as well?

Comment: @cabrerahector Can you kindly add your comment as an answer? It DOES answer the question.

Comment: No problem, @Theson. Just posted my comment as an answer below. Added some more details as well.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation refers to an actual TAB. Not four spaces.

> Your indentation should always reflect logical structure. Use **real tabs** and **not spaces**, as this allows the most flexibility across clients.

Source: [Indentation - PHP Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#indentation)

Note that the usage of spaces is allowed sometimes though:

> Exception: if you have a block of code that would be more readable if things are aligned, use spaces:
>
> ```
> [tab]$foo   = 'somevalue';
> [tab]$foo2  = 'somevalue2';
> [tab]$foo34 = 'somevalue3';
> [tab]$foo5  = 'somevalue4';
> ```